# React Js: Store React Component in a variable and use it later

Tags: reactjs

I have a case where I need to return `React Component` from a func called `func` and want to render it in another file. The component renders as `[object Object]`

Link to the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/60365/)

```
class A extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var val = B.func("hii");
    return (
      <div>
        {val}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

B.js

```
let B = {
  func: function(msg) {
    return msg.replace(/i/g, function myFunction(x){
      var imgTag = <span>Hello</span>
      return imgTag;
    });
  }
}
```

I want to render this but it renders as [object Object]. I am not able to see whats wrong.

Comment: It works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/60363/

Comment: @ChristopherChiche Actually I am storing it in redux store, then i'm accessing it from redux store. In that case it goes like that. i'll update the question

Comment: It would be perfect if you could reproduce the issue in the jsFidddle as well :)

Comment: @ChristopherChiche I have created the issue in a Fiddle, please check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have some text, where you want to replace some parts of text with react component, you can't do that just with `replace` function, because you trying to convert React Element Object to string. 
I think better way, will be match your pattern and create an array of elements, to render that in React.

For example, you need to transofrm:

`'some text REPLACEME other text'`

To:

`['some text', React.createElement('A', {}, null), 'other text']`

Cant provide better code example right now, sorry ;D

Comment: Thanks this helps. I got the issue that its the replace function which is killing the logic. I'll replace it with something else.